# Eliminar texto hasta la primera ocurrencia en Java

Tags: java

¿Cómo se puede eliminar parte de un texto hasta encontrar la primera ocurrencia?  Eliminando también la ocurrencia encontrada.

**Texto de ejemplo:**

```
<div>soy la primera linea</div><div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```

la ocurrencia seria `</div>` así el texto final deberia ser

```
<div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es parsear HTML, mejor utiliza una librería adecuada en lugar de utilizar regex o similar.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza solo es para ese propósito, estoy realizando un sistema de changelog y quiero que el primero bloque sea lo de "whats the new"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza `indexOf` para encontrar la primera ocurrencia de `</div>`, y obtén la subcadena con `substring`:

```
String str = "<div>soy la primera linea</div><div>soy la segunda linea</div>";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("</div>") + 6);
System.out.println(str); // <div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Sin usar expresiones regulares podrías hacer algo así:

```
public class Ejemplo {

  public static void main(String[ ] arg) 
  {
    String cadena = "<div>soy la primera linea</div><div>soy la segunda linea</div>";
    System.out.println(cadena);

    String patron = "</div>";
    int posicion = cadena.indexOf(patron);

    System.out.println(cadena.subSequence(posicion+patron.length(),cadena.length()));

  }
}
```

Salida:

```
yo@pc:/tmp⟫ javac Ejemplo.java  
yo@pc:/tmp⟫ java Ejemplo
<div>soy la primera linea</div><div>soy la segunda linea</div>
<div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```

Échale un vistazo a la referencia del api java sobre la clase [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 5):

Hay millones de motivos por los que no se debería manipular HTML con métodos de `String` o `regex`. Hay mucha información en la web, pero para no entrar en tanto detalle, el siguiente HTML haría que fallen la mayoría de esos intentos:

```html
<!-- quiero eliminar hasta el primer </div> -->
<DIV id='elid'>soy la primera linea</DIV 
><div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```

---

### Usando [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Es la forma correcta de hacerlo, ya que representa al HTML como un documento con nodos, y te evitará futuros dolores de cabeza.

```java
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
```

Para convertir un `String` en `Document`:

```java
public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception
{
    xml = "<Wrapper>" + xml + "</Wrapper>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    return builder.parse(is);
}
```

Y luego, recorremos todos los nodos que están en la raíz del documento, hasta encontrar el primer `<div>`. A partir de ahí, vamos añadiendo a un `StringBuilder`.

```java
String texto = "<!-- quiero eliminar hasta el primer </div> -->\n<DIV id='elid'>soy la primera linea</DIV \n ><div>soy la segunda linea</div>";

//String -> doc
Document doc = loadXMLFromString(texto);

//Construir el serializer y sacar la declaración XML
DOMImplementationLS lsImpl = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation().getFeature("LS", "3.0");
LSSerializer lsSerializer = lsImpl.createLSSerializer();
lsSerializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);

//Bucle en todos los nodos de la raíz
Node docRoot = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList childNodes = docRoot.getChildNodes();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Boolean divEncontrado = false;
for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    if (!divEncontrado) {
        //Se encontró?
        divEncontrado = childNodes.item(i).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("div");
    } else {
        //Si se encontró antes, agregarlo al StringBuilder
        sb.append(lsSerializer.writeToString(childNodes.item(i)));
    }
}
String resultado = sb.toString();

System.out.println(resultado);
```

**Resultado:**

```
<div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```

[<kbd>Demo en ideone.com</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ULAyMw)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes intentar con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
<div>.*?</div>
```

[image: visual]

Esto es:

```java
String input = "<div>soy la primera linea</div><div>soy la segunda linea</div>";

System.out.println(
    input.replaceFirst("<div>.*?</div>", "")
);  // imprime "<div>soy la segunda linea</div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

yo realizo de esta forma:

```
    String pattern = "</div>";
    String cadena = "<div>soy la primera linea</div><div>soy la segunda linea</div>";
    System.out.println(cadena.substring(cadena.indexOf(pattern) + pattern.length()));
```

obtienes como salida:

```
<div>soy la segunda linea</div>
```